# Algorithm for finding out the cheapst combination

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I have a few sets which are like

```
SET A(1,2,3,11,10)  - $30
SET B(2,5,8)        - $20
SET C(6)             -$25
SET D(6,8)           -$30
SET E(7,5)           -$20
SET F(5,6,7,8,9,10)  -$60
.
.
.
```

and so on...
All are random,
Now consider sets D,E and F
I want to buy the cheapest combination for a set, SET Q(7,8,6,5)
the answer should be SET D + SET E, not the SET F

Please link... thanks

Comment: -1: Try using the code highlighting, and provide an example so that people who will take the time to help you can "follow along at home".

Comment: [Brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search).

Comment: This also sounds awfully like homework or some other kind of contrived exercise?

Comment: Zed,
can u pls explain

Comment: It's a NP-complete problem. That means, enumerate all possibilities and take the cheapest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called Weighted Set Covering.

You'll get lots of results searching for that term on [Google.](http://www.google.com/search?q=weighted+set+cover)